# spring jboss ehcache

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss, ehcache

I am trying to configure my application to make use of ehCache.  I am using Spring 2.5.6, Jboss 5.1.0 GA and its embedded version of Hibernate along with ehCache-core V2.3.1.

I have done the following configuration:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
    <!-- prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>  
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop-->
  </props>
</property>
```

This is my ehcache.xml

```
<defaultCache eternal="false" 
        overflowToDisk="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="50000" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="30" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
/>
<cache name="com.model.SystemProperty"
        maxElementsInMemory="5000"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
/>
```

This file is located in my class path.

I have added the following to my domain object:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="vsg.ecotrak.admin.store.domain.Store", include="non-lazy")
```

When I start up the server, it gets stuck.  Here is the output:

```
13:17:09,000 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled
13:17:09,000 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: enabled
13:17:09,016 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
13:17:09,017 INFO  [RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge] Cache provider: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider
```

Any Ideal as to why this is happening?

I am running on a Windows 7 64 bit if that matters.

---

I downgraded the ehcache jar to V 1.2.3 and the server now starts.

Comment: Raise JBoss's logging to DEBUG (using `conf/jboss-log4j.xml`), and see what it says then.

Answer (score 0):

Does using hibernate.cache.region.factory_class to net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory rather than the Cache Provider (deprecated) method making it any better ?

Also could you do a thread dump when it hangs ?